# React - How to use bind with an event handler and preserve event object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have something along these lines:

```
<IconButton
  icon="icon-delete"
  onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, itemName)}
/>
```

When the `deleteItem` function fires, though, the `event` argument is lost. And referring to `this` only refers to the React component. How do I preserve/pass `event` when using `bind`?

Answer (score 0):

`this.deleteItem.bind(this, itemName)` means that the value of `itemName` will be assigned to the first parameter of `this.deleteItem`.

Therefore the event object will be assigned to the *second parameter*.

Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more information about `.bind`.

Comment: if the method is called in a callback like debounce, `event.persist()` is required to be called before access to the event

Answer (score -1):

in ES6 syntax. You can use ::this.deleteItem

```
// This is binding the function onFormSubmit to this fn.bind(this)
<form onSubmit={::this.onFormSubmit}>
</form>
```

I have some codes like yours here.

```
<button className="removeitem" onClick={this.handleClickRemoveFromCart(item, item.id)}>
   <i className="icon icon-close -x3" />
</button>


handleClickRemoveFromCart(item, id) {
    return this.props.onRemoveFromCart(item, id);
};
```

Comment: You sure that's not ES7?

Comment: Sorry, its ES7.. my bad. :)